# How to Count cells since the last filled cell in a column, and repeat for each time a cell is filled

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a tracking spreadsheet to track dry streak calcs for certain drops from a boss in a video game. I want to be able to easily see my dry streaks by having the sheet count the amount if boss kills since the last drop.

I have the following:

```
=IF(B2="",COUNTBLANK(B2:INDEX($B2:B,MATCH(FALSE,($B2:B=""),0))),"")+1
```

where column A is the boss kill count, and column B is filled if a drop is received.

the above formula works to an extent of what i want, but the order is upside down. I'd also like it to only show the "count since last drop" when a cell in column B is filled., rather than every cell showing it.

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10lS9kNPdWctHIsB5qtC0LSkhyky_1ahkV0RsY5gFwvo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `column A` is a sequence of numbers as depicted in the sample you can use `formula 1` and `formula 2` is stand-alone just based on `column B`. Please test them out.

formula 1:

```
=let(a,filter(A2:A,B2:B="drop"),byrow(A2:A,lambda(z,IF(offset(z,,1)="drop",z-xlookup(offset(z,-1,),a,a,,-1),))))
```

formula 2:

```
=let(a,filter(row(B:B)-1,B:B="drop"),byrow(B2:B,lambda(z,IF(z="drop",row(z)-1-xlookup(row(offset(z,-2,)),a,a,,-1),))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another option that instead of looking for values it just makes a cumulative count.

```
=SCAN(0,B1:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(B:B)-1),LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="drop",1,a+1)))
```

`B1:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(B:B)-1)` is a replacement for OFFSET so it is a bit more economic in resources

[image]

Then you can just hide the values when B is empty:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="","",SCAN(0,B1:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(B:B)-1),LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="drop",1,a+1)))))
```

[image]